# Why does a Timed Out error occur with this code CodingBat excersise ?

Tags: java, arrays

The question is this:

Given an array of positive ints, return a new array of length "count" containing the first even numbers from the original array. The original array will contain at least "count" even numbers.

My solution is:

```
public int[] copyEvens(int[] nums, int count) {
int counter=0;
int[] arr = new int[count];
while (counter<count)
{
  if (nums[counter]%2==0)
{
  counter++;
 arr[counter]=nums[counter];
}
}
return arr;
}
```

When I run this in CodingBat, it says Timed Out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code

```
while (counter<count)
{
  if (nums[counter]%2==0)
  {
    counter++;
    arr[counter]=nums[counter];
  }
}
```

if the `nums[counter]` evaluation is false, then `counter` will not be incremented and there will be an infinte loop.  There is no way for `counter` to exceed `count` and it will keep on looping.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help

Comment: Done. I also want to help some people out on stack over flow. Is it possible for me to answer questions on here, or am I too much of a beginner for that